# Paypal payflow link setup no "PayPal Express Checkout" feildset

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, express-checkout

I'm trying to learn and setup embedded payments. I'm following the tutorial at : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyiv3ndRcZI

In part of that tutorial in paypal manager there is an  "PayPal Express Checkout" feildset where you can set a live account email and sandbox account email.

When I login to my manager I do not have this feildset to enter this information. It's not there at all.

any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or what I have to do to get the Express Checkout fieldset to show up?

The end goal is for me to be using it for the purpose in this question [Send money to any PayPal account and receive payment notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513348/send-money-to-any-paypal-account-and-receive-payment-notification)

Comment: In what way is this related to programming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to contact the PayPal support team as they need to enable some setting on your Payflow account . Once its enabled you will see the option there to put your PayPal email address .