# express checkout section missing in paypal manager hosted checkout set up

Tags: php, paypal

I am working with payflow hosted checkout pages. I got the link explaining the setup of test account on [here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1493&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en).

In above docs under Part III: Setting Up the Manager - Point no 4. I am not able to see **PayPal Express Checkout** section. Tutorial video and docs say that I have to add my sandbox business account here.

If anybody is faced similar situation before ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just contact the PayPal tech support to add that option in your manager account by submitting to the below portal :

https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask

[Paypal payflow link setup no "PayPal Express Checkout" feildset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572927/paypal-payflow-link-setup-no-paypal-express-checkout-feildset/27635506#27635506)